# Why is it possible to "apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base" on Raspbian?

Tags: ros, docker, raspberrypi, raspbian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought that Debian packages for ROS Indigo were not available on Raspbian. However, [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/PabloGN/Docker-raspbian-ros-indigo/blob/master/Dockerfile) does:

```
echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

and then

```
# install ros packages
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
    ros-indigo-ros-core=1.1.4-0* \
    ros-indigo-ros-base=1.1.4-0* \
    && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and it seems to work just fine. There's even an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pablogn/rpi-ros-core-indigo/) on Docker Hub and I was also able to replicate it in this [modified Dockerfile](https://github.com/spmaniato/resin-raspbian-ros-indigo-qemu/blob/master/Dockerfile) which uses a different Raspbian base image.

How come this is possible? I thought I'd have to build from source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242119/why-is-it-possible-to-%22apt-get-install-ros-indigo-ros-base%22-on-raspbian?/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By most accounts, this probably shouldn't work. And even if it all installs, there's no guarantee that everything will work correctly.

The biggest reason that it works is because the author specifies the `trusty` repository, which contains ROS packages for armhf, and those packages have dependencies that appear to be satisfied (at least in name) on raspbian.

Within an Ubuntu release, the developers make sure that there aren't [ABI-breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) changes to packages, and they explicitly save the breaking changes for releases. The fact that the Trusty packages work at all on raspbian is mostly due to very few changes in the libc ABI, and a good deal of luck. If you try to install packages that depend on more complex libraries that change more frequently, you'll probably run into either missing dependencies, dependencies that are the wrong version, or dependencies that have quietly changed between releases and just don't work.

The "Supported/Tested" list on http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM is user-contributed, so it's not perfect. It's not clear why someone added a non-Ubuntu distribution to that list, and it isn't something that should be supported, so I've removed it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-10**:
On my RPi3 (physical and Docker image), I've been able to `apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation` without any problems. But I haven't actually run/tested it yet. And you're saying that even if it *seems* to work, the "hack" won't be reliable. Makes sense. Thanks a lot for the input Austin!